# Solr 4 Webinterface strange Query Output

Tags: java, user-interface, solr

I've installed Solr 4 on my server. The basic querying is working just fine. Just the resultset get's rendered unreadable as seen in picture [image: Rendering of results in Solr4].

If you compare it to the screenshots from the solr4 website: [image].

I tried Safari and Chrome and both show this unreadable output.
Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your browser tries do display the XML and strips all the tags. Unfortunately, this is common with Chrome, Safari and IE.

I use Firefox for accessing solrs webinterface and get the syntax highlighted view of xml-data.

If you can not use Firefox, a workaround is to open the actual url (the part you covered in red) and than use your browser's 'View Source' functionality. It will show you the plain text xml sent by Solr.

Comment: That's what I did. I installed a plugin for safari that does syntax highlighting. But I don't want to use the link and open a new page or use firefox. Is it possible to have this (firefox) behavior also in safari?

Comment: I don't think so. There are some plugins for Safari, but most of them seem outdated. The Solr Developers are aware of this, as you can read from this Issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3840 and it is fixed in Solr 4.1.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is XML output in Solr 4.0. Try switching to Ruby or other output format in the drop-downs.

It is fixed in Solr 4.1.